# laravel app on localhost , no styling and no javascript files loaded?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to fix some bugs of  a website that's hosted on server so the client provided me the address to the server with username and password ,
I logged into the server and downloaded the files in public_html which is a Laravel application, I tried to open the website on localhost to find that there is no styling and no JavaScript files loaded in the website locally, although I can find the files with the correct addresses in page source
I have been trying to solve this problem for about 3 hours and searched google for answers but could not find answers , thanks.

Comment: There's just not enough here to be able to help you in my opinion. Consider checking out [mcve].

Comment: sorry about that but what can i provide you to help me

Comment: It's possible it has some sort of asset pipeline or is using Laravel Mix to compile things.

Comment: it's using laravel 5.0 so it's not using laravel mix

Comment: it's showing this in terminal every time i try to access the styling or js files from source page      Invalid request (Unexpected EOF )

Comment: i found the solution , it wasn't starting correctly using  php artisan serve  but it started correctly using  php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 from the root directory of the project

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify. [mahmudy-91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7007539/mahmudy-91) found an answer himself and posted it in the comments:

> i found the solution , it wasn't starting correctly using php artisan serve but it started correctly using php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 from the root directory of the project